# How to calculate spectral density in R without canned function?

Tags: r, gauss

// Estimate autocovariance

`L=ltp_CR(n); gk=acf(x,L,0); gk=(rev(gk)|1|gk).*(x'x/n);`
is there a way to convert the above code in Gauss to R?
Thanks

I am planning to calculate the spectral density in R without using canned functions. Unfortunately, I don't know how to calculate L as in the code in R

Comment: what are `canned` functions? also `L = ltp_CR(n)` ie it seems that the function `ltp_CR` is evaluated at `n` to obtain `L`. Just do the same in R